# How to autostart LXterminal in openbox maximized?

Tags: openbox, autostart, lxterminal

The problem is that I found a solution for my `.config/openbox/rc.xml`, but not for `.config/openbox/autostart.sh`. Normally, it's just the command with options like in CLI, but `man lxterminal` doesn't seem to provide them.

Could you briefly tell me the options for the `autostart.sh`?

Comment: It is a bash script file. I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "options". Also, have a look at the openbox [docs](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Autostart). Given that, you'd have to add a line like `yourcommand &` to launch it on login.

Answer (score 1):

lxterminal doesn't provide any options for maximizing window, so you may want to consider using another terminal application that provide this option, like

```
xterm -maximized
```

Or you can add these lines into applications section inside ~/.config/openbox/rc.xml

```
<application class="lxterminal">
    <maximized>true</maximized>
</application>
```

but every instance of lxterminal would be maximized by default.

P.S. Another solution is using **wmctrl** program inside your script, for example:

```
#!/bin/sh

wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
# your script start here
neofetch    
read
# end of the script
```

Comment: Sorry, changing ~/.config/openbox/rc.xml didn't work for me.